# How do I get a list of devices connected to same wifi network in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I want to make a file sharing app and for that I need to find nearby devices which are on the same wifi network whether it's android devices or iOS devices.

What is the best way to find nearby devices?

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. Also, please edit your expectations alongside that process. **Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service**. Thanks!

Comment: The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 1):

one of simple ways would be to implement `Bonjour` - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software).

There is a lot of projects about that https://github.com/search?q=Bonjour

Comment: Do I get device name and profile pic like xender does using bonjour?

Comment: you can get anything you want. Bonjour is just protocol.

Comment: I want to connect cross platform device to send and receive file same as other file sharing app does.